# Do "SO" and "RO" postfixes have a standard meaning, as in "EnvelopeSO"?

Tags: terminology, abbreviation, acronym

I'm working with a communication layer and there are objects called "*EnvelopeSO" and "*EnvelopeRO".

I've tried to find them at wikipedia, search engines, here, but they are hard to search for.

Are these postfixes frequently used? What do they stand for (abbreviation, acronym)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These postfixes commonly says what is the role of the object.

For objects intended to transfer data, it is common to add the **TO** suffix, so we have `ServerTO`, `AccountTO`, `UserTO`, `CompanyTO`, `CustomerTO`, `SaleItemTO`, etc. **TO** is an acronym for *Transfer Object*. A variation of this is the **DTO** suffix which means *Data Transfer Object*.

For objects intended to control the database access we have the **DAO** suffix for *Data Access Object*, so we have a `UserDAO`, `CustomerDAO`, `SalesDAO`, etc.

The **UI** or **GUI** suffix is frequently used for user interface objects. These are acronyms for *Graphical User Interface* or simply *User Interface*.

Other common uses of this are **VO** for *Value Object* and **DO** for *Domain Object*.

I once saw **BE** suffix for *Business Entity*, **SL** for *Service Locator* and **PB** for *Page Bean*.

Although this is a common practice in lot of places, I weakly recommend against it. A descriptive name is normally much better than a cryptic acronym suffix (or prefix), but if you can't find one that is not too long, use the acronym. Instead of `CustomerTO` or `CustomerDTO` you could name it just `Customer`. Instead of `SalesDAO` you could name it `SalesPersistence` or `SalesDatabase`. This eliminates the problem of trying to understand what the suffix should mean when you get a `VendorDSA` or a `PersonTF`.

In partcular the **DTO**, **TO**, **DAO**, **UI**, **GUI**, **VO** and **DO** suffix are very common and widespread. Other suffixes are normally obscure.

For your case in special, I have no idea of what is **SO** and **RO**, and I can't do anything better than just guess, which again shows that a descriptive name is better than an acronym as a suffix. My best bet is that **SO** is *Service Object* and **RO** is *Resource Object*.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, **RO** meant *REST object*, standing for [REpresentational State Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST).